# Copy text into clipboard in Linux with Swift

Tags: swift, linux

I have been trying to find a way to manage the clipboard in Linux using Swift. My initial thought was with Glibc, but there is nothing (that I could find) about managing the clipboard with this library.

- How would be a sensible approach to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing. Using the clipboard in Linux is a pita anyway, and you won't find this in glibc but in higher levels like X11 (with Xlib for example) or other more recent standards. I suppose a solution would be to find a C/C++ library which handles the clipboard(s) correctly (there's a few on GitHub) and then call it from Swift.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: If I may ask, which library did you use and how did you implement it?

Comment: I never made it. I moved to Nim a little after that.